# How to make git use just one level in directory

Tags: git

I want to use git to track my config files so I have to make a repository in my home directory. However I don't want it to be a repository for all the subfolders because I don't want to give it a command on accident from a sub-directory which was meant for another repo.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Maybe it's possible for you to move configs to other folder - the one that doesn't have subfolders.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but then I would have to always write a linking config in the default directory for the programs to look for it.

Comment: This might help: http://blog.smalleycreative.com/tutorials/using-git-and-github-to-manage-your-dotfiles/

Comment: See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46538/are-there-pitfalls-to-putting-home-in-git-instead-of-symlinking-dotfiles

Comment: Thanks jcm, these are very interesting sources. I think I will use the method described at smalleycreative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `.gitignore` file with following content:

```
/*/**
```

For more information about `.gitignore`, see http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: Thank you, that is a nice and easy solution. But jcm (see comments on my question) already convinced me that what I want to do is not a good solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

- you can create a folder in your home directory ... `dotfiles` and you this folder as a git repo...
- then copy the files you want to add them to this git repo (example `.bashrc`,`.vimrc` )
- then remove the files from the home directory
- then add them again to the home directory using `ln -s ~/dotfiles/.bashrc ~/.bashrc`
- this will make changing `~/.bashrc` or `~/dotfiles/.bashrc` be catchable using `git status`

i use this my self... and i find it cleaner than the way you are trying to do

you can follow this [simple tutorial](http://blog.smalleycreative.com/tutorials/using-git-and-github-to-manage-your-dotfiles/)

Comment: Thank you, I will use this method and also include a script wicht does all the symlinking in the installation for me.